# How to avoid text shifting in css?

Tags: html, css, frontend

As you can see in the image below, I am using arrows to next and previous page. However, when the No. of digits in the page number changes, the text shifts to accommodate the extra digit. How do I solve this?

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfE6e.gif)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: try to work with &nbsp; tag.

Comment: I got it working by adding the min-width property. Thanks!